# Select option won't fire jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some problems with what should be a simple jQuery show/hide based on a select's value.  The select is hidden by default based on other selects, which might be why it's not working?

Unfortunately I can't change the source code in any manner, I can only add a function like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#question-select-1271443').change(function() {
    var selection = $(this).val();
    if (selection == 'CIIC') {
      $('#question-select-1082380').show();
    } else {
      $('#question-select-1082380').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: please add some of your code

Comment: Is there not code above?

Comment: There is, but the code you've shown works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/kasvemxz/. Hence why @j08691 was asking for a more complete sample of your codebase which actually shows the issue. The only reason it wouldn't work is if the `#question-select-1271443` element is dynamically appended after the page loads. Via AJAX for example.

Answer (score 0):

function `val()` extract the value of the attribute value of the option selected. Maybe you are trying to extract the content of the option. Example:

```
<select id="sas">
  <option value="hi">Hello</option>
</select>
```

```js
$("#sas").change(function(){
  $(this).val(); // This return hi
  $("option:selected", this).text() // This return Hello
});
```

Comment: This is completely unrelated to what the question is asking